# Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes issue with Matlab

Tags: c#, matlab, ascii, wav

The `WriteWavHeader` function implements a WAV header. The problem is that when I try to read the WAV file in Matlab with `wavread`, I fail. By adding a breakpoint in `wavread`, I've inspected that although Matlab reads the 'WAVE', 'fmt ', and 'data' headers fine (i.e., `ck.ID` is equal to `'WAVE'`, `'fmt '` and `'data'` respectively in every iteration), it can't correctly read the `'end of file'` string. Specifically, `ck.ID` is equal to a bunch of weird ASCII characters. When I hard code that `ck.ID = 'end of file'`, I manage to get the wav file read. Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

```
static void WriteWavHeader(Stream stream, int dataLength)
    {
        using (var memStream = new MemoryStream(64))
        {
            int cbFormat = 18; //sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX)

            WAVEFORMATEX format = new WAVEFORMATEX()
            {
                wFormatTag = 1,
                nChannels = 1,
                nSamplesPerSec = 16000,
                nAvgBytesPerSec = 32000,
                nBlockAlign = 2,
                wBitsPerSample = 16,
                cbSize = 0
            };

            using (var binarywriter = new BinaryWriter(memStream))
            {
                //RIFF header
                WriteString(memStream, "RIFF");
                binarywriter.Write(dataLength + 8 + cbFormat + 8 + 4); //File size - 8

                WriteString(memStream, "WAVE");
                WriteString(memStream, "fmt ");
                binarywriter.Write(cbFormat);

                //WAVEFORMATEX
                binarywriter.Write(format.wFormatTag);
                binarywriter.Write(format.nChannels);
                binarywriter.Write(format.nSamplesPerSec);
                binarywriter.Write(format.nAvgBytesPerSec);
                binarywriter.Write(format.nBlockAlign);
                binarywriter.Write(format.wBitsPerSample);
                binarywriter.Write(format.cbSize);

                //data header
                WriteString(memStream, "data");
                binarywriter.Write(dataLength);

                memStream.WriteTo(stream);
                WriteString(memStream, "end of file");

            }
        }
    }

static void WriteString(Stream stream, string s)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
        stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking at this bit of code (`edit wavread` at about line 208)?

```
function [ck,msg] = read_ckinfo(fid)

msg     = '';
ck.fid  = fid;
ck.Data = [];
err_msg = getString(message('MATLAB:audiovideo:wavread:TruncatedChunkHeader'));

[s,cnt] = fread(fid,4,'char');

% Do not error-out if a few (<4) trailing chars are in file
% Just return quickly:
if (cnt~=4),
    if feof(fid),
        % End of the file (not an error)
        ck.ID = 'end of file';  % unambiguous chunk ID (>4 chars)
        ck.Size = 0;
    else
        msg = err_msg;
    end
    return
end
...
```

As far as I can tell there is no valid ID/chunk called "end of file" (it's also not four characters long). This function simply returns the `'end of file'` string to the `find_cktype` function (see lines 76 and 99) as a flag. In other words you appear to be writing a string of data (your "weird ASCII characters") to your WAV file with:

```
WriteString(memStream, "end of file");
```

The way to check for the end of a file in Matlab is with [`feof`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/feof.html) or check the length of the output returned by `fread`.

If you want to read the WAV, I think that you'll write some actual WAV data that matches up with what your header says.

Comment: Actually, I added the line WriteString(memStream, "end of file"); to see if Matlab required an "end of file" string in its wav header. The original wav header (https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/) ends with the data. I had tried the C# code without the "end of line" ID but it didn't work in Matlab, either...

Comment: It probably didn't work because your file was inconsistent. You can't just have a header and no data. And even with a header and data, everything must presumably match up with what the header claims is in the file. The link you gave is a good starting point. You just need to make sure everything is bit-perfect.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the C# code is consistent with the link, because the wav file produced, plays just fine in VLC player, Windows Media Player and many others. Moreover, if I right click on the file for details, the correct bit rate and duration are displayed, which means that the fmt and data headers are just fine. There only seems to be a problem with how I should end the header... Thank you for helping by the way!

Comment: No, I wouldn't assume that at all. Media players are designed to be *very* lenient with broken and malformed files. They can try lots of different things if they detect that something is wrong. Matlab, however, is generally not for good reasons. The same goes for many of Matlab's media reading functions. Check that the endianness of all of the parts is right. And try comparing the output file from your code with a file exported from a quality encoder (i.e., not just some random WAV you find on the Internet) using HEX viewer. Also, did I answer your original question by the way?